# How to get elements hidden with 'ng-hide'?

Tags: angularjs

I need to color some icons, and those colors depends on visibility of some div elements. Those div are hidden with ng-hide angular directive. So, how to get all elements which are hidden with ng-hide? I tried jQuery method 'visible' but it doesn't work, also tried hasClass('ng-hide'), but also with no success.

Comment: The divs are hidden base on values in the model. The icon colors depend on the visibility of the divs. Hence, the icon colors re also based on the values in the model. Don't try to use the dom. Use the model.

Comment: I'm starter with Angular so I'm still trying to catch whole structure and stop jQuery thinking :) Can you write me some model example similar to my case? Thanks.

Comment: You should provide an example and try something, and I would be glad to show you how to modify it.